# I just installed pycharm and I can open my excel workbook. I recieve the error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, excel, ubuntu, pycharm, openpyxl

I am using Ubuntu-pycharm-openpyxl. My code is:

```
import openpyxl as xl
import os
p = os.getcwd ()
print(p)
filename = 'c:/home/elinor/Documents/data.xlsx'
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename)
```

It returns:

```
/home/elinor/PycharmProjects/untitled1/venv/bin/python /home/elinor/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/scratch_1.py
/home/elinor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/elinor/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 6, in <module>
    wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename) 
  File "/home/elinor/PycharmProjects/untitled1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 313, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "/home/elinor/PycharmProjects/untitled1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "/home/elinor/PycharmProjects/untitled1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 1251, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:/home/elinor/Documents/data.xlsx'**
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the file path you've mentioned is correct? If yes, then please try as below filename = r'c:/home/elinor/Documents/data.xlsx'

Comment: I checked the file path by viewing its properties and it shows the path as:/home/elinor/Documents. I tried using: r'c:/home/elinor/Documents/data.xlsx' and it returned the same error message.

Comment: Is it possible that it is having issues because the document was created using LibreOffice and then was saved as an .XLSX file?

Comment: Path you have mentioned and  path you have taken from the properties don't have "c:" . Are you using Mac OS?

Comment: I am using an hp with windows and Ubuntu dual installed.

Comment: Remove "c:" and try it

Comment: hahahahaha, im dead. That worked? Why did that work? This has been so frustrating.

Comment: From the error messages I could see that the path was starting as "/home/elinor" not "c:/home/elinor"